# How can I show the total of column values in the last row of a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which shows data from a Microsoft Access database. Now, I want to add a column "total" in the last row of the `DataGridView`.

I did this in HTML as follows, but how can I do exactly the same in VB.NET?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:last-child {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bikram</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Abhram</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ram</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>75</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code for your data table would be good

Comment: yes, and in VB.NET